# Basic Checkbox Group handle on change example not working

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, checkbox

I am following the [basic checkbox group](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/4ceb14a5d13175b0ed34521e347eee448ba84f45/edit) example in salesforce documentation, but ran into a really weird issue in the handle change event handler:

JS

```
@track roleCheckboxValues = [];
get roleCheckboxOptions() {
    return [
        { label: 'Staff', value: 'staff' },
        { label: 'Test', value: 'test },
    ];
}

handleRolesCheckbox(e) {
    console.log(e.detail.value);
    this.roleCheckboxValues = e.detail.value;
    console.log(this.roleCheckboxValues)
}
```

HTML

```
<lightning-checkbox-group name="Role Checkbox Group" label="Include" options={roleCheckboxOptions} value={roleCheckboxValues} onchange={handleRolesCheckbox}></lightning-checkbox-group>
```

Now, when I click the different boxes, they toggle on and off, but as you can see I put two console logs. However, the first log (e.detail.value) it prints the correctly, newly selected options, but the second log (this.roleCheckboxValues) prints nothing every time even though you it clearly assigns `d.detail.value` to `this.roleCheckboxValues`...

Here is what the console prints out when I start with `none selected` then `select Staff` then `select Test` then `deselect staff` then `deselect test`:

[image: console log]

Why isn't `this.roleCheckboxValues` not being assigned to `d.detail.value` like it's suppose to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a property as track, it adds a proxy object on top of it that facilitates UI updates on value changes.

What you see `Proxy {}` is a complex Object that contains your array value and extra tracking features.

Instead of `console.log(this.roleCheckboxValues)` use `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.roleCheckboxValues));` it will show the actual values and same is being updated on the UI.

Playground Link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/77JMjuytd/1/edit

[image]